# "valor ausente donde TRUE/FALSE es necesario" error en un bucle en R

Tags: r, bucle-for, rstudio

No veo el error, este es el bucle:

```
IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta <- c()

for (i in 1:nrow(datosSeleccionados)) {
  if (datosSeleccionados$CURRENT_STATE.x[i] == "Cerrada" || datosSeleccionados$CURRENT_STATE.x[i] == "Cerrado"){
    datosSeleccionados$IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta[i] <- 0
  }
  else if(datosSeleccionados$CURRENT_STATE.x[i]=="Anulada" || datosSeleccionados$CURRENT_STATE.x[i]=="Eliminada"){
    datosSeleccionados$IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta[i] <- "Anulada"
  }
  else
    datosSeleccionados$IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta[i] <- 1
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido @miguel a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Se ha empezado definiendo un vector `IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta <- c()` antes del bucle `for` lo cual está bien.

No obstante en este caso en particular, se está asignando valores a una **columna** `IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta` -no confundir con el vector inicial- del **data.frame** `datosSeleccionados` que aún no existe.

Para solucionar esto, el vector (no la columna) `IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta <- c()` tiene que ser el que recolecte los valores dentro del bucle `for`, aquí la idea inicial de como funciona:

```
IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta<-c()
IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta<-c(IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta,1)
IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta
[1] 1

IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta<-c(IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta,20)
IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta
[1]  1 20
```

Por tanto una vez el vector `IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta` haya recorrido todas la `filas` puede ser asignado a la columna `IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta` de `datosSeleccionados` (con este proceso se crea recién la columna antes citada).

```
datosSeleccionados<-data.frame(CURRENT_STATE.x=c("Cerrada","Cerrado","Anulada","Eliminada","EnEspera","Aprobada" ))
datosSeleccionados

  CURRENT_STATE.x
1         Cerrada
2         Cerrado
3         Anulada
4       Eliminada
5        EnEspera
6        Aprobada

IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta <- c()

for (i in 1:nrow(datosSeleccionados)) {
    if (datosSeleccionados$CURRENT_STATE.x[i] == "Cerrada" || datosSeleccionados$CURRENT_STATE.x[i] == "Cerrado"){
        IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta <- c(IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta,0)
    }
    else if(datosSeleccionados$CURRENT_STATE.x[i]=="Anulada" || datosSeleccionados$CURRENT_STATE.x[i]=="Eliminada"){
        IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta <- c(IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta,"Anulada")
    }
    else
        IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta <- c(IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta,1)
}

# Se crea la columna 'IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta' mediante la asignación del vector
# 'IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta' que tiene el número de elementos iguales al número 
# de filas del data.frame 'datosSeleccionados'
datosSeleccionados$IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta <- IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta
datosSeleccionados

  CURRENT_STATE.x IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta
1         Cerrada                        0
2         Cerrado                        0
3         Anulada                  Anulada
4       Eliminada                  Anulada
5        EnEspera                        1
6        Aprobada                        1
```

Answer (score 0):

Debe agregar una verificación adicional para asegurarse de que no falte el valor antes de realizar la operación lógica. Esto se puede hacer usando la función `is.na()` de la siguiente manera:

```
IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta <- c()

for (i in 1:nrow(datosSeleccionados)) {
  if (is.na(datosSeleccionados$CURRENT_STATE.x[i])) {
    datosSeleccionados$IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta[i] <- NA
  }
  else if (datosSeleccionados$CURRENT_STATE.x[i] == "Cerrada" || datosSeleccionados$CURRENT_STATE.x[i] == "Cerrado") {
    datosSeleccionados$IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta[i] <- 0
  }
  else if (datosSeleccionados$CURRENT_STATE.x[i] == "Anulada" || datosSeleccionados$CURRENT_STATE.x[i] == "Eliminada") {
    datosSeleccionados$IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta[i] <- "Anulada"
  }
  else {
    datosSeleccionados$IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta[i] <- 1
  }
}
```

Al verificar si el valor es NA en el primer `if`, evitamos realizar cualquier operación lógica y simplemente asignamos NA a `datosSeleccionados$IncidenciaTodaviaAbierta[i]`. Esto debería prevenir el error mencionado.